# ¿Cómo declarar una variable global para hacer referencia al modelo?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

me encuentro utilizando un framework MVC de PHP que es muy simple a la hora de utilizar, se llama [MINI](https://github.com/panique/mini3) y mi pregunta es como me podrían ayudar para que la carga de un modelo no sea llamado en cada método de un controlador como en el ejemplo del controlador de SongsController

EJEMPLO:

```
    public function index()
    {
    // Instance new Model (Song)
    $Song = new Song();
    // getting all songs and amount of songs
    $songs = $Song->getAllSongs();
    $amount_of_songs = $Song->getAmountOfSongs();

   // load views. within the views we can echo out $songs and $amount_of_songs easily
    require APP . 'view/_templates/header.php';
    require APP . 'view/songs/index.php';
    require APP . 'view/_templates/footer.php';
}
```

me gustaría saber cómo se puede declarar de forma global, para que no se tenga que llamar en cada metodo de un controlador, les agradeceria mucho y espero que me hayan entendido.

Comment: Defínelo como propiedad del controlador `private $_song;`, en el constructor asignas el modelo `$this->_song = new Song();` y ya tienes `$this->_song` disponible en todos los métodos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho la ayuda. me gustaría hacerte otra pregunta con respecto al microFramework, la podría hacer aquí mismo o te puedo contactar ?

Comment: Lo mejor es que hagas otra pregunta, siempre y cuando sea una duda sobre código que no puedes hacer funcionar, si es basada en opinión la van a borrar.